# Windows XP logon log?

Tags: windows-xp

Is there a log on Windows XP which contains recent logins on a domain? I can't remote into a machine because it might cause someone to lose their work. Only via shares.

Answer (score 4):

[Logon events are audited in the Security Event Log.](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows+Operating+System&ProdVer=5.0&EvtID=528&EvtSrc=Security&LCID=1033) You're looking for Event ID 528 on XP.

These are not stored in plain text. You'll need to view the logs using the event viewer.

Comment: As a follow on - you can do this by opening Event Viewer on your computer, right clicking on "Event Viewer (Local)" and selecting "Connect to another computer".

Comment: You could also do `tasklist /s [hostname]`.  If explorer.exe is running, someone is logged in.